# Alt buttons not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, alt-tab, alt

Since yesterday, both **alt** buttons on my *Asus laptop* stopped working. However, they are working fine on *Onscreen keyboard*. I use Windows 10 which was updated recently.

Here's the list of things that I last did/installed on my laptop before this happened:

1. Updated my Fortnite game.
2. In an attempt to boost the laptop performance, I changed the performance settings from 'Best Performance' to 'Custom'and selected the options as shown:
   [image: Custom]
3. After making the above changes, the font of the letters became thin and unclear. So I googled for a solution and followed the instructions given in answers.microsoft.com. The instructions were - [image: Click]

   However, when I tried to run the .reg file, I received an error. So I left it at that and used another way to change the font.
4. Downloaded Atom code editor. Installed it but received an error

And here is the list of things which I tried to fix the alt button:

1. Restarted Windows explorer
2. Uninstalled keyboard drivers and reinstalled
3. Did *System Restore* to an earlier point. Did not fix the issue. However, the laptop was running slow so reverted back to the current point by using *Undo System Restore*
4. Checked if alt is working in Safe Mode. Not working.

Nothing worked. I'm wondering if the registry file that I created might have caused this.
How to fix the issue? Can someone help me, please?

**Edit**:

I'm attaching **Atom installation setup log file** and **Font and FontSubstitutes registry files** in this link:
[Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s1A3oCAkeZsOxU8jy_4zOOIZES6XBL34?usp=sharing)

Font registry:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Arial (TrueType)"="arial.ttf"
"Arial Black (TrueType)"="ariblk.ttf"
"Arial Bold (TrueType)"="arialbd.ttf"
"Arial Bold Italic (TrueType)"="arialbi.ttf"
"Arial Italic (TrueType)"="ariali.ttf"
"Bahnschrift (TrueType)"="bahnschrift.ttf"
"Calibri (TrueType)"="calibri.ttf"
"Calibri Bold (TrueType)"="calibrib.ttf"
"Calibri Bold Italic (TrueType)"="calibriz.ttf"
"Calibri Italic (TrueType)"="calibrii.ttf"
"Calibri Light (TrueType)"="calibril.ttf"
"Calibri Light Italic (TrueType)"="calibrili.ttf"
"Cambria & Cambria Math (TrueType)"="cambria.ttc"
"Cambria Bold (TrueType)"="cambriab.ttf"
"Cambria Bold Italic (TrueType)"="cambriaz.ttf"
"Cambria Italic (TrueType)"="cambriai.ttf"
"Candara (TrueType)"="candara.ttf"
"Candara Bold (TrueType)"="candarab.ttf"
"Candara Bold Italic (TrueType)"="candaraz.ttf"
"Candara Italic (TrueType)"="candarai.ttf"
"Candara Light (TrueType)"="candaral.ttf"
"Candara Light Italic (TrueType)"="candarali.ttf"
"Comic Sans MS (TrueType)"="comic.ttf"
"Comic Sans MS Bold (TrueType)"="comicbd.ttf"
"Comic Sans MS Bold Italic (TrueType)"="comicz.ttf"
"Comic Sans MS Italic (TrueType)"="comici.ttf"
"Consolas (TrueType)"="consola.ttf"
"Consolas Bold (TrueType)"="consolab.ttf"
"Consolas Bold Italic (TrueType)"="consolaz.ttf"
"Consolas Italic (TrueType)"="consolai.ttf"
"Constantia (TrueType)"="constan.ttf"
"Constantia Bold (TrueType)"="constanb.ttf"
"Constantia Bold Italic (TrueType)"="constanz.ttf"
"Constantia Italic (TrueType)"="constani.ttf"
"Corbel (TrueType)"="corbel.ttf"
"Corbel Bold (TrueType)"="corbelb.ttf"
"Corbel Bold Italic (TrueType)"="corbelz.ttf"
"Corbel Italic (TrueType)"="corbeli.ttf"
"Corbel Light (TrueType)"="corbell.ttf"
"Corbel Light Italic (TrueType)"="corbelli.ttf"
"Courier New (TrueType)"="cour.ttf"
"Courier New Bold (TrueType)"="courbd.ttf"
"Courier New Bold Italic (TrueType)"="courbi.ttf"
"Courier New Italic (TrueType)"="couri.ttf"
"Ebrima (TrueType)"="ebrima.ttf"
"Ebrima Bold (TrueType)"="ebrimabd.ttf"
"Franklin Gothic Medium (TrueType)"="framd.ttf"
"Franklin Gothic Medium Italic (TrueType)"="framdit.ttf"
"Gabriola (TrueType)"="Gabriola.ttf"
"Gadugi (TrueType)"="gadugi.ttf"
"Gadugi Bold (TrueType)"="gadugib.ttf"
"Georgia (TrueType)"="georgia.ttf"
"Georgia Bold (TrueType)"="georgiab.ttf"
"Georgia Bold Italic (TrueType)"="georgiaz.ttf"
"Georgia Italic (TrueType)"="georgiai.ttf"
"Impact (TrueType)"="impact.ttf"
"Ink Free (TrueType)"="Inkfree.ttf"
"Javanese Text (TrueType)"="javatext.ttf"
"Leelawadee UI (TrueType)"="leelawui.ttf"
"Leelawadee UI Bold (TrueType)"="leelauib.ttf"
"Leelawadee UI Semilight (TrueType)"="leeluisl.ttf"
"Lucida Console (TrueType)"="lucon.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Unicode (TrueType)"="l_10646.ttf"
"Malgun Gothic (TrueType)"="malgun.ttf"
"Malgun Gothic Bold (TrueType)"="malgunbd.ttf"
"Malgun Gothic SemiLight (TrueType)"="malgunsl.ttf"
"Microsoft Himalaya (TrueType)"="himalaya.ttf"
"Microsoft JhengHei & Microsoft JhengHei UI (TrueType)"="msjh.ttc"
"Microsoft JhengHei Bold & Microsoft JhengHei UI Bold (TrueType)"="msjhbd.ttc"
"Microsoft JhengHei Light & Microsoft JhengHei UI Light (TrueType)"="msjhl.ttc"
"Microsoft New Tai Lue (TrueType)"="ntailu.ttf"
"Microsoft New Tai Lue Bold (TrueType)"="ntailub.ttf"
"Microsoft PhagsPa (TrueType)"="phagspa.ttf"
"Microsoft PhagsPa Bold (TrueType)"="phagspab.ttf"
"Microsoft Sans Serif (TrueType)"="micross.ttf"
"Microsoft Tai Le (TrueType)"="taile.ttf"
"Microsoft Tai Le Bold (TrueType)"="taileb.ttf"
"Microsoft YaHei & Microsoft YaHei UI (TrueType)"="msyh.ttc"
"Microsoft YaHei Bold & Microsoft YaHei UI Bold (TrueType)"="msyhbd.ttc"
"Microsoft YaHei Light & Microsoft YaHei UI Light (TrueType)"="msyhl.ttc"
"Microsoft Yi Baiti (TrueType)"="msyi.ttf"
"MingLiU-ExtB & PMingLiU-ExtB & MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB (TrueType)"="mingliub.ttc"
"Modern (All res)"="modern.fon"
"Mongolian Baiti (TrueType)"="monbaiti.ttf"
"MS Gothic & MS UI Gothic & MS PGothic (TrueType)"="msgothic.ttc"
"MV Boli (TrueType)"="mvboli.ttf"
"Myanmar Text (TrueType)"="mmrtext.ttf"
"Myanmar Text Bold (TrueType)"="mmrtextb.ttf"
"Nirmala UI (TrueType)"="Nirmala.ttf"
"Nirmala UI Bold (TrueType)"="NirmalaB.ttf"
"Nirmala UI Semilight (TrueType)"="NirmalaS.ttf"
"Palatino Linotype (TrueType)"="pala.ttf"
"Palatino Linotype Bold (TrueType)"="palab.ttf"
"Palatino Linotype Bold Italic (TrueType)"="palabi.ttf"
"Palatino Linotype Italic (TrueType)"="palai.ttf"
"Roman (All res)"="roman.fon"
"Script (All res)"="script.fon"
"Segoe MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="segmdl2.ttf"
"Segoe Print (TrueType)"="segoepr.ttf"
"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)"="segoeprb.ttf"
"Segoe Script (TrueType)"="segoesc.ttf"
"Segoe Script Bold (TrueType)"="segoescb.ttf"
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"="seguibl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"="seguibli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguiemj.ttf"
"Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"="seguihis.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"="seguili.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"="seguisbi.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"="segoeuisl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"="seguisli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
"SimSun & NSimSun (TrueType)"="simsun.ttc"
"SimSun-ExtB (TrueType)"="simsunb.ttf"
"Sitka Small & Sitka Text & Sitka Subheading & Sitka Heading & Sitka Display & Sitka Banner (TrueType)"="Sitka.ttc"
"Sitka Small Bold & Sitka Text Bold & Sitka Subheading Bold & Sitka Heading Bold & Sitka Display Bold & Sitka Banner Bold (TrueType)"="SitkaB.ttc"
"Sitka Small Bold Italic & Sitka Text Bold Italic & Sitka Subheading Bold Italic & Sitka Heading Bold Italic & Sitka Display Bold Italic & Sitka Banner Bold Italic (TrueType)"="SitkaZ.ttc"
"Sitka Small Italic & Sitka Text Italic & Sitka Subheading Italic & Sitka Heading Italic & Sitka Display Italic & Sitka Banner Italic (TrueType)"="SitkaI.ttc"
"Sylfaen (TrueType)"="sylfaen.ttf"
"Symbol (TrueType)"="symbol.ttf"
"Tahoma (TrueType)"="tahoma.ttf"
"Tahoma Bold (TrueType)"="tahomabd.ttf"
"Times New Roman (TrueType)"="times.ttf"
"Times New Roman Bold (TrueType)"="timesbd.ttf"
"Times New Roman Bold Italic (TrueType)"="timesbi.ttf"
"Times New Roman Italic (TrueType)"="timesi.ttf"
"Trebuchet MS (TrueType)"="trebuc.ttf"
"Trebuchet MS Bold (TrueType)"="trebucbd.ttf"
"Trebuchet MS Bold Italic (TrueType)"="trebucbi.ttf"
"Trebuchet MS Italic (TrueType)"="trebucit.ttf"
"Verdana (TrueType)"="verdana.ttf"
"Verdana Bold (TrueType)"="verdanab.ttf"
"Verdana Bold Italic (TrueType)"="verdanaz.ttf"
"Verdana Italic (TrueType)"="verdanai.ttf"
"Webdings (TrueType)"="webdings.ttf"
"Wingdings (TrueType)"="wingding.ttf"
"Yu Gothic Bold & Yu Gothic UI Semibold & Yu Gothic UI Bold (TrueType)"="YuGothB.ttc"
"Yu Gothic Light & Yu Gothic UI Light (TrueType)"="YuGothL.ttc"
"Yu Gothic Medium & Yu Gothic UI Regular (TrueType)"="YuGothM.ttc"
"Yu Gothic Regular & Yu Gothic UI Semilight (TrueType)"="YuGothR.ttc"
"Courier 10,12,15"="COURE.FON"
"Courier 10,12,15 (120)"="COURF.FON"
"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SERIFE.FON"
"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (120)"="SERIFF.FON"
"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SSERIFE.FON"
"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (120)"="SSERIFF.FON"
"Small Fonts"="SMALLE.FON"
"Small Fonts (120)"="SMALLF.FON"
"Holo MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="holomdl2.ttf"
"ROG FONTS (TrueType)"="ROGFonts-Regular.otf"
"Agency FB Bold (TrueType)"="AGENCYB.TTF"
"Agency FB (TrueType)"="AGENCYR.TTF"
"Algerian (TrueType)"="ALGER.TTF"
"Book Antiqua Bold (TrueType)"="ANTQUAB.TTF"
"Book Antiqua Bold Italic (TrueType)"="ANTQUABI.TTF"
"Book Antiqua Italic (TrueType)"="ANTQUAI.TTF"
"Arial Narrow (TrueType)"="ARIALN.TTF"
"Arial Narrow Bold (TrueType)"="ARIALNB.TTF"
"Arial Narrow Bold Italic (TrueType)"="ARIALNBI.TTF"
"Arial Narrow Italic (TrueType)"="ARIALNI.TTF"
"Arial Rounded MT Bold (TrueType)"="ARLRDBD.TTF"
"Baskerville Old Face (TrueType)"="BASKVILL.TTF"
"Bauhaus 93 (TrueType)"="BAUHS93.TTF"
"Bell MT (TrueType)"="BELL.TTF"
"Bell MT Bold (TrueType)"="BELLB.TTF"
"Bell MT Italic (TrueType)"="BELLI.TTF"
"Bernard MT Condensed (TrueType)"="BERNHC.TTF"
"Book Antiqua (TrueType)"="BKANT.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Bold (TrueType)"="BOD_B.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Bold Italic (TrueType)"="BOD_BI.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Black Italic (TrueType)"="BOD_BLAI.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Black (TrueType)"="BOD_BLAR.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="BOD_CB.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Condensed Bold Italic (TrueType)"="BOD_CBI.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Condensed Italic (TrueType)"="BOD_CI.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Condensed (TrueType)"="BOD_CR.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Italic (TrueType)"="BOD_I.TTF"
"Bodoni MT Poster Compressed (TrueType)"="BOD_PSTC.TTF"
"Bodoni MT (TrueType)"="BOD_R.TTF"
"Bookman Old Style (TrueType)"="BOOKOS.TTF"
"Bookman Old Style Bold (TrueType)"="BOOKOSB.TTF"
"Bookman Old Style Bold Italic (TrueType)"="BOOKOSBI.TTF"
"Bookman Old Style Italic (TrueType)"="BOOKOSI.TTF"
"Bradley Hand ITC (TrueType)"="BRADHITC.TTF"
"Britannic Bold (TrueType)"="BRITANIC.TTF"
"Berlin Sans FB Bold (TrueType)"="BRLNSB.TTF"
"Berlin Sans FB Demi Bold (TrueType)"="BRLNSDB.TTF"
"Berlin Sans FB (TrueType)"="BRLNSR.TTF"
"Broadway (TrueType)"="BROADW.TTF"
"Brush Script MT Italic (TrueType)"="BRUSHSCI.TTF"
"Bookshelf Symbol 7 (TrueType)"="BSSYM7.TTF"
"Californian FB Bold (TrueType)"="CALIFB.TTF"
"Californian FB Italic (TrueType)"="CALIFI.TTF"
"Californian FB (TrueType)"="CALIFR.TTF"
"Calisto MT (TrueType)"="CALIST.TTF"
"Calisto MT Bold (TrueType)"="CALISTB.TTF"
"Calisto MT Bold Italic (TrueType)"="CALISTBI.TTF"
"Calisto MT Italic (TrueType)"="CALISTI.TTF"
"Castellar (TrueType)"="CASTELAR.TTF"
"Century Schoolbook (TrueType)"="CENSCBK.TTF"
"Centaur (TrueType)"="CENTAUR.TTF"
"Century (TrueType)"="CENTURY.TTF"
"Chiller (TrueType)"="CHILLER.TTF"
"Colonna MT (TrueType)"="COLONNA.TTF"
"Cooper Black (TrueType)"="COOPBL.TTF"
"Copperplate Gothic Bold (TrueType)"="COPRGTB.TTF"
"Copperplate Gothic Light (TrueType)"="COPRGTL.TTF"
"Curlz MT (TrueType)"="CURLZ___.TTF"
"Elephant (TrueType)"="ELEPHNT.TTF"
"Elephant Italic (TrueType)"="ELEPHNTI.TTF"
"Engravers MT (TrueType)"="ENGR.TTF"
"Eras Bold ITC (TrueType)"="ERASBD.TTF"
"Eras Demi ITC (TrueType)"="ERASDEMI.TTF"
"Eras Light ITC (TrueType)"="ERASLGHT.TTF"
"Eras Medium ITC (TrueType)"="ERASMD.TTF"
"Felix Titling (TrueType)"="FELIXTI.TTF"
"Forte (TrueType)"="FORTE.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Book (TrueType)"="FRABK.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Book Italic (TrueType)"="FRABKIT.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Demi (TrueType)"="FRADM.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Demi Cond (TrueType)"="FRADMCN.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Demi Italic (TrueType)"="FRADMIT.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Heavy (TrueType)"="FRAHV.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Heavy Italic (TrueType)"="FRAHVIT.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (TrueType)"="FRAMDCN.TTF"
"Freestyle Script (TrueType)"="FREESCPT.TTF"
"French Script MT (TrueType)"="FRSCRIPT.TTF"
"Footlight MT Light (TrueType)"="FTLTLT.TTF"
"Garamond (TrueType)"="GARA.TTF"
"Garamond Bold (TrueType)"="GARABD.TTF"
"Garamond Italic (TrueType)"="GARAIT.TTF"
"Gigi (TrueType)"="GIGI.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT (TrueType)"="GIL_____.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT Bold (TrueType)"="GILB____.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT Bold Italic (TrueType)"="GILBI___.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT Condensed (TrueType)"="GILC____.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT Italic (TrueType)"="GILI____.TTF"
"Gill Sans Ultra Bold Condensed (TrueType)"="GILLUBCD.TTF"
"Gill Sans Ultra Bold (TrueType)"="GILSANUB.TTF"
"Gloucester MT Extra Condensed (TrueType)"="GLECB.TTF"
"Gill Sans MT Ext Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="GLSNECB.TTF"
"Century Gothic Bold (TrueType)"="GOTHICB.TTF"
"Century Gothic Bold Italic (TrueType)"="GOTHICBI.TTF"
"Century Gothic Italic (TrueType)"="GOTHICI.TTF"
"Goudy Old Style (TrueType)"="GOUDOS.TTF"
"Goudy Old Style Bold (TrueType)"="GOUDOSB.TTF"
"Goudy Old Style Italic (TrueType)"="GOUDOSI.TTF"
"Goudy Stout (TrueType)"="GOUDYSTO.TTF"
"Harlow Solid Italic (TrueType)"="HARLOWSI.TTF"
"Harrington (TrueType)"="HARNGTON.TTF"
"Haettenschweiler (TrueType)"="HATTEN.TTF"
"High Tower Text (TrueType)"="HTOWERT.TTF"
"High Tower Text Italic (TrueType)"="HTOWERTI.TTF"
"Imprint MT Shadow (TrueType)"="IMPRISHA.TTF"
"Informal Roman (TrueType)"="INFROMAN.TTF"
"Blackadder ITC (TrueType)"="ITCBLKAD.TTF"
"Edwardian Script ITC (TrueType)"="ITCEDSCR.TTF"
"Kristen ITC (TrueType)"="ITCKRIST.TTF"
"Jokerman (TrueType)"="JOKERMAN.TTF"
"Juice ITC (TrueType)"="JUICE___.TTF"
"Kunstler Script (TrueType)"="KUNSTLER.TTF"
"Wide Latin (TrueType)"="LATINWD.TTF"
"Lucida Bright (TrueType)"="LBRITE.TTF"
"Lucida Bright Demibold (TrueType)"="LBRITED.TTF"
"Lucida Bright Demibold Italic (TrueType)"="LBRITEDI.TTF"
"Lucida Bright Italic (TrueType)"="LBRITEI.TTF"
"Lucida Calligraphy Italic (TrueType)"="LCALLIG.TTF"
"Lucida Fax Regular (TrueType)"="LFAX.TTF"
"Lucida Fax Demibold (TrueType)"="LFAXD.TTF"
"Lucida Fax Demibold Italic (TrueType)"="LFAXDI.TTF"
"Lucida Fax Italic (TrueType)"="LFAXI.TTF"
"Lucida Handwriting Italic (TrueType)"="LHANDW.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Regular (TrueType)"="LSANS.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Demibold Roman (TrueType)"="LSANSD.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Demibold Italic (TrueType)"="LSANSDI.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Italic (TrueType)"="LSANSI.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Typewriter Regular (TrueType)"="LTYPE.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Typewriter Bold (TrueType)"="LTYPEB.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Typewriter Bold Oblique (TrueType)"="LTYPEBO.TTF"
"Lucida Sans Typewriter Oblique (TrueType)"="LTYPEO.TTF"
"Magneto Bold (TrueType)"="MAGNETOB.TTF"
"Maiandra GD (TrueType)"="MAIAN.TTF"
"Matura MT Script Capitals (TrueType)"="MATURASC.TTF"
"Mistral (TrueType)"="MISTRAL.TTF"
"Modern No. 20 (TrueType)"="MOD20.TTF"
"Monotype Corsiva (TrueType)"="MTCORSVA.TTF"
"Niagara Engraved (TrueType)"="NIAGENG.TTF"
"Niagara Solid (TrueType)"="NIAGSOL.TTF"
"OCR A Extended (TrueType)"="OCRAEXT.TTF"
"Old English Text MT (TrueType)"="OLDENGL.TTF"
"Onyx (TrueType)"="ONYX.TTF"
"MS Outlook (TrueType)"="OUTLOOK.TTF"
"Palace Script MT (TrueType)"="PALSCRI.TTF"
"Papyrus (TrueType)"="PAPYRUS.TTF"
"Parchment (TrueType)"="PARCHM.TTF"
"Perpetua (TrueType)"="PER_____.TTF"
"Perpetua Bold (TrueType)"="PERB____.TTF"
"Perpetua Bold Italic (TrueType)"="PERBI___.TTF"
"Perpetua Italic (TrueType)"="PERI____.TTF"
"Perpetua Titling MT Bold (TrueType)"="PERTIBD.TTF"
"Perpetua Titling MT Light (TrueType)"="PERTILI.TTF"
"Playbill (TrueType)"="PLAYBILL.TTF"
"Poor Richard (TrueType)"="POORICH.TTF"
"Pristina (TrueType)"="PRISTINA.TTF"
"Rage Italic (TrueType)"="RAGE.TTF"
"Ravie (TrueType)"="RAVIE.TTF"
"MS Reference Sans Serif (TrueType)"="REFSAN.TTF"
"MS Reference Specialty (TrueType)"="REFSPCL.TTF"
"Rockwell Condensed (TrueType)"="ROCC____.TTF"
"Rockwell Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="ROCCB___.TTF"
"Rockwell (TrueType)"="ROCK.TTF"
"Rockwell Bold (TrueType)"="ROCKB.TTF"
"Rockwell Bold Italic (TrueType)"="ROCKBI.TTF"
"Rockwell Extra Bold (TrueType)"="ROCKEB.TTF"
"Rockwell Italic (TrueType)"="ROCKI.TTF"
"Century Schoolbook Bold (TrueType)"="SCHLBKB.TTF"
"Century Schoolbook Bold Italic (TrueType)"="SCHLBKBI.TTF"
"Century Schoolbook Italic (TrueType)"="SCHLBKI.TTF"
"Script MT Bold (TrueType)"="SCRIPTBL.TTF"
"Showcard Gothic (TrueType)"="SHOWG.TTF"
"Snap ITC (TrueType)"="SNAP____.TTF"
"Stencil (TrueType)"="STENCIL.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Bold (TrueType)"="TCB_____.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Bold Italic (TrueType)"="TCBI____.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="TCCB____.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold (TrueType)"="TCCEB.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Condensed (TrueType)"="TCCM____.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT (TrueType)"="TCM_____.TTF"
"Tw Cen MT Italic (TrueType)"="TCMI____.TTF"
"Tempus Sans ITC (TrueType)"="TEMPSITC.TTF"
"Viner Hand ITC (TrueType)"="VINERITC.TTF"
"Vivaldi Italic (TrueType)"="VIVALDII.TTF"
"Vladimir Script (TrueType)"="VLADIMIR.TTF"
"Wingdings 2 (TrueType)"="WINGDNG2.TTF"
"Wingdings 3 (TrueType)"="WINGDNG3.TTF"
"DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerif.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Mono Bold Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf"
"Gentium Basic (TrueType)"="GenBasR.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Condensed (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Bold (TrueType)"="DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Condensed (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Condensed Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf"
"Gentium Book Basic (TrueType)"="GenBkBasR.ttf"
"Arimo (TrueType)"="Arimo-Regular.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf"
"Gentium Book Basic Bold Italic (TrueType)"="GenBkBasBI.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Condensed Italic (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Condensed Bold Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf"
"Gentium Book Basic Bold (TrueType)"="GenBkBasB.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Bold Italic (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf"
"OpenSymbol (TrueType)"="opens___.ttf"
"Gentium Book Basic Italic (TrueType)"="GenBkBasI.ttf"
"Arimo Bold (TrueType)"="Arimo-Bold.ttf"
"Gentium Basic Italic (TrueType)"="GenBasI.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Condensed Bold (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans ExtraLight (TrueType)"="DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Condensed Bold Italic (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Bold (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf"
"Gentium Basic Bold Italic (TrueType)"="GenBasBI.ttf"
"Gentium Basic Bold (TrueType)"="GenBasB.ttf"
"DejaVu Serif Italic (TrueType)"="DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans (TrueType)"="DejaVuSans.ttf"
"Arimo Bold Italic (TrueType)"="Arimo-BoldItalic.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Mono (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansMono.ttf"
"DejaVu Sans Mono Bold (TrueType)"="DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf"
"Arimo Italic (TrueType)"="Arimo-Italic.ttf"
"Edo SZ (TrueType)"="edosz.ttf"
"AzonixRegular (TrueType)"="Azonix.otf"
"Qardoos Personal Use Regular (TrueType)"="Qardoos-Personal-Use.otf"
"Angelface (TrueType)"="Angelface.otf"
"Open Sans (TrueType)"="OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
"Open Sans Semibold (TrueType)"="OpenSans-Semibold.ttf"
"AdobeDevanagari-Regular (TrueType)"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Resource\\Font\\AdobeDevanagari-Regular.otf"
"AdobeDevanagari-Bold (TrueType)"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Resource\\Font\\AdobeDevanagari-Bold.otf"
"AdobeDevanagari-BoldItalic (TrueType)"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Resource\\Font\\AdobeDevanagari-BoldItalic.otf"
"AdobeDevanagari-Italic (TrueType)"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Resource\\Font\\AdobeDevanagari-Italic.otf"
"ZWAdobeF (TrueType)"="ZWAdobeF.TTF"
"Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"="FontAwesome.otf"
"Font Awesome 5 Free Solid"="FontAwesomeSolid.otf"
"Futura Lt BT"="futura_light_bt.ttf"
"Futura-Bold"="FuturaBold.ttf"
"Futura-Medium"="FuturaMedium.ttf"
"HelveticaNeueLT Std"="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf"
"HelveticaNeueLT Std Med"="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf"
```

FontSubstitutes registry:

```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Arabic Transparent"="Arial"
"Arabic Transparent Bold"="Arial Bold"
"Arabic Transparent Bold,0"="Arial Bold,178"
"Arabic Transparent,0"="Arial,178"
"Arial Baltic,186"="Arial,186"
"Arial CE,238"="Arial,238"
"Arial CYR,204"="Arial,204"
"Arial Greek,161"="Arial,161"
"Arial TUR,162"="Arial,162"
"Courier New Baltic,186"="Courier New,186"
"Courier New CE,238"="Courier New,238"
"Courier New CYR,204"="Courier New,204"
"Courier New Greek,161"="Courier New,161"
"Courier New TUR,162"="Courier New,162"
"Helv"="MS Sans Serif"
"Helvetica"="Arial"
"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"
"Tahoma Armenian"="Tahoma"
"Times"="Times New Roman"
"Times New Roman Baltic,186"="Times New Roman,186"
"Times New Roman CE,238"="Times New Roman,238"
"Times New Roman CYR,204"="Times New Roman,204"
"Times New Roman Greek,161"="Times New Roman,161"
"Times New Roman TUR,162"="Times New Roman,162"
"Tms Rmn"="MS Serif"
"MS Shell Dlg"="Microsoft Sans Serif"
```

Keyboard Layout - English (United States) 
Language package - English (United States) and English (United Kingdom)

Comment: The font looked due to your Performance Options, the solution to that problem, would have been to revert those changes.  However, you by using the registry file, you potentially made changes to your system.  I am guessing you have no idea what the actual error you received was?  Can you export the following two keys from your system `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes` without the data from those two keys I won't be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What keyboard layout is your system configured to use.  What language packs are installed on your system?  Please [edit] to include this information and the information from my previous comment.  Please include any errors you have received, for instance the error you received, when you installed Atom.

Comment: @old_school: I would guess that one of installed applications owns the **ALT** as global hotkey and does not forward this key down no another applications. You should determine what is the application did that and remove it.

Comment: @Jackdaw I added the Atom installation setup log in my post. Kindly check it. The setup log file popped up during the installation with an error notification.

Comment: @Ramhound  I added the registry file exports and the keyboard layout and language package information in my post. I also attached the Atom installation setup log.

Comment: @old_school: The Atom installation setup log does not provide useful information for me. But as I marked in comment above, you can do the following to find out if some process still the **ALT** key events: read the solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645062/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645062/6630084) provided for another question. For this purpose install the `spy++` application from [https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus](https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus). You are welcome with any question related to the `https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645062/6630084`!

Comment: You could have just provided a text copy of the registry keys, I can't access drive.google.com during the week, so I won't be able to see what your system's font is exactly.  I suspect I know what happen but I will have to confirm.

Comment: @Jackdaw When I checked for alt+tab hotkey in the spy++ tool, it shows that the hotkey is owned by EXPLORER process.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my post and added a text copy of the registry keys.

Comment: The good news is the registry modification you ran, if you provided us the entire us exactly what you ran, did not actually apply to your registry.  Have you tried to undo the change to performance options?  Likewise, the errors contained within your Atom text document have nothing to do with Atom.  You have errors about Grammarly, Microsoft Teams, something called Squirrel.  Your fonts would have nothing to do with keyboard shortcuts working or not working anyways. Try connecting an external USB keyboard to the device and verify if this isn't a simple case of a broken keyboard button.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your response. I'll check with an external keyboard then.

Comment: @Ramhound it's working with an external keyboard. So is it a hardware issue with my laptop?

Comment: That’s what the test suggests, it certainly isn’t the registry edit that failed to apply due to an error, and none of those performance options would alter the behavior of your ALT key